# mod-xsendfile 404 caused by SELinux

Tags: php, apache, http-status-code-404, selinux, x-sendfile

Ok.  Wanted to share this - took me 10 hours to figure out.

I had properly installed mod-xsendfile, following the good instructions [here](https://tn123.org/mod_xsendfile/).

I also configured xsendfile correctly in my /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf file, adding the settings:
    XSendFile on
    XSendFilePath /var/files_need_valid_session_to_view/

And I knew my code for generating the X-SENDFILE header was correct: it was working on a different server.  However, I was **getting 404 errors, no matter what I did.**  My OS was CentOS 6.4 final.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Label your directory with the correct SELinux label. See [How to label an apache directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19576167/403-error-on-apache-server-with-django-application) that is the same case for your folder '/var/files_need_valid_session_to_view/'.

Disabling SELinux is an unnecessary security risk.

Answer (score 0):

[Disabling SELinux](http://www.crypt.gen.nz/selinux/disable_selinux.html) solved the problem.  I'm sure, if this was a production server, that I should configure SELinux to allow Apache to view `/var/files_need_valid_session_to_view/`, but for my purposes, this was enough.

```
$ sudo su
  -or-
$ su
# echo 0 >/selinux/enforce    // Note - you cannot just say sudo for this line: the stuff after the carrot will not be super-user.  sudo su, then do this.

-to perminantly disable, across reboots, see the link at the top of my answer-
```